# Can we pass form element values to a function in the same web page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <form action="">
   ......any form elements......
 </form>
 </body>
 <script>
 function fn() {

 }
 </script>
 </html>
```

Instead of an URL in the action attribute, is there a way (or any other alternate way) to pass values of form to a function (within script tags) within this same web page?

Comment: You can use the onsubmit event of the form to use custom javascript to process what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I have done it for years. It works on all browsers - for really old browsers you can even change document.getElementById("form1") to document.form1 if you add name="form1" to the form tag.

Note: Before jQuery, it was in many places recommended practice to use [eventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)  such as

```
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit",
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    ... some code 
  });
```

but I personally prefer either jQuery or the simpler onsubmit...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
    var val1 = this.field1.value;
    if (val1=="") {
      alert('Field1 cannot be empty');
      this.field1.focus();
      return false;
    }
    // return true to submit, return false to stay on the page.
    return true; 
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" action="">
  <input type="text" name="field1" value="" />
  .
  .
  .
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If it MUST be inline, then I strongly recommend

```
<head>
<script>
function validate(theForm) {
  var val1 = theForm.field1.value;
  .
  .
    return false;// cancel
  .
  .
  return true; // allow submit
}
</script>
</head>

<form onsubmit="return validate(this)">
```

**UPDATE**

```
to just change some span or div on the page do this:

<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
    var val1 = this.field1.value;
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML="This is the value "+val1;
    return false; // do not submit/refresh the page
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" action="">
  <input type="text" name="field1" value="" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're going for best practices, I'd mention `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` versus those inline event listeners.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks. Done. I never use them myself due to cross browser issues. Instead I use jQuery exclusively, completely skipping the addEventListener era ;)

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<form  id="frm">    
<input type="button" onclick="fn()" value="Submit to function"/>
</form>
```

javascript

```
function fn(){
var frm = document.getElementById("frm");
var elements = frm.elements;
var len = elements.length;
// do something with elements
 for(var i =0; i < len; i++){
  console.log("%s = %s", elements[i].name, elements[i].value);
 }
}
```

Comment: I would save `frm.elements.length` to a temporary variable, since now, you're building a array of the form's elements, then getting the length of the array, for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: If you pass this.form you do not need to use document.getElementById inside the function you assigned inline. You use form access in frm.elements anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually sending text values to the function and I'm using      document.getElementById("").innerHTML instead of      console.log to print it on the same page. The value is printed but the page refreshes immediately and becomes blank. Any immediate resolution?

Comment: Yes - look at my suggestion. You need to return false from the handler to stay on the page!

Comment: Thanks. That worked! But I also tried with another set of code using button (onClick) instead of Submit and      return false did not work for that. Any ideas?